# Apply PaperTrail to all models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, paper-trail-gem

I don't think there is an easy way to apply PaperTrail to all model except by declaring `has_paper_trail` in each one.
What I want to accomplish is to leverage the features of PaperTrail (or another gem, like Auditable, Vestal Versions) to all the models. For example, I want to include models generated by gems and engines (Rails 3).

Any pointers on how to apply a "global" PaperTrail (or similar gem)?

Comment: I've used the same idea that is in the answer, but with a small update (using the table_name, instead of class name, because I have anonymous class). https://gist.github.com/dmitry/b94860e44516e417f6f4

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For **Rails 5.0+** (if app has the `ApplicationRecord` class)

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.inherited subclass
    super
    subclass.send(:has_paper_trail)
  end
end
```

---

For older Rails versions

```
# config/initializers/paper_trail_extension.rb 
ActiveRecord::Base.singleton_class.prepend Module.new {
  def inherited subclass
    super
    skipped_models = ["ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration", "PaperTrail::Version", "ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session"]
    unless skipped_models.include?(subclass.to_s)
      subclass.send(:has_paper_trail)
    end
  end
}
```

(It is important that you use `{/}` and not `do/end` after `Module.new` because of operator precedence).

Comment: It seems this technique no longer works in PT 4.0, or at least requires some caution, if you have any HABTM associations. (https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/657)

Comment: I don't think the issue is with paper_trail being on 4.0 but with HABTM relations which are not supported by paper_trail (as also noted on that issue).

Comment: Using rails 5.0+ can't I just add `has_paper_trail` to ApplicationRecord? Instead of doing this definition? I've tried it, and it worked all right, but I don't if it has any bad consequences...

Comment: I would also add a method for paper trail config. `subclass.send(:has_paper_trail, paper_trail_config)` and default it to  return `{}`. This let's you easily override the options for each subclass, when you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the ActiveRecord::Base module with a monkeypatch:

```
# config/initializers/active_record_paper_trail.rb
class ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
end
```

Might do the job, depends if it can include the gem at that point... try it and see

Comment: thanks Matt. I had to add the check defined?(has_paper_trail.

Comment: actually, this does not work as expected, because PaperTrail attaches itself to Active Record::Base, not to the models. I will leave the answer as accepted for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can just inherit all your models from a MyModel class (similar to using an ApplicationController)...

```
class Posts < MyModel
end

class Comments < MyModel
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
     self.abstract_class = true

     has_paper_trail
end
```

Don't forget the `self.abstract_class = true` in the base model.